# What has been changed in Stranger Things since it was originally released?

Tags: production, stranger-things, edition-comparison

In a recent [Variety interview with the Duffer Brothers](https://variety.com/2022/tv/news/stranger-things-season-4-duffer-brothers-spinoff-1235301947/) (creators of *Stranger Things*) they state this:

> We have George Lucas’d things also that people don’t know about,” he continued, while declining to detail specific alterations from previous seasons.
>
> Ross Duffer said, “You do have the physical copies though, the Blu-rays and stuff — you’d have to compare.”

What changes did they make?

Comment: We have always been at war with Eastasia....

Comment: Seems like it's more CGI improvements than anything else

Comment: Samwise shoots first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit with new information from an authoritative source:**

The show writers [weighed in on Twitter](https://twitter.com/strangerwriters/status/1551901196700590080) saying there will not be any content edits, even denying the potential retroactive edit of Will's birthday. The edit I mentioned below of Jonathan's photo-taking in S1E2 was apparently a Tiktok hoax.

**Original (wrong) answer:**

I just came across [an article](https://www.yahoo.com/now/creepy-jonathan-moment-edited-stranger-130000924.html) saying they removed part of the scene in Season 1 where Jonathan Byers takes pictures of Nancy undressing at Steve's house after the pool party. The photo he took still appears in a later episode where Steve and his friends confront Jonathan for being creepy and break his camera.

[This theory](https://screenrant.com/did-vecna-take-will-in-stranger-things-season-1) showed up in June 2022, and it says in the first episode of Season 1 when Will was heading home and crashed his bike there were Vecna-style grandfather clock chimes. I haven't been able to verify by comparing with the blu-rays.

I haven't seen any others yet but I have been following Stranger Things articles closely looking for any other announcements.

Comment: Probably a smart choice to make him seem less creepy. But what is this? "Insider could not verify the validity of these claims." There are used DVDs out there, along with copies of the show saved and distributed through torrent sites and so forth. How could they not confirm or disprove this claim?

Comment: Anyway, if one were to have...access...to copies from July 15, 2016, one would probably see that after Jonathan lowers his camera, he raises it again, but only Barb is shown through the camera. Hypothetically.

Comment: In the original version, though, he clearly only lowers his camera after he has already  taken a picture of Nancy taking her shirt off (i.e., he lowers it when she and Steve start kissing). Perhaps the new version is edited to place the scene where he lowers the camera a bit earlier.

Comment: @Adamant what precisely was changed? Is the article correct?

Comment: I will award this a bounty if this can be better confirmed.

Comment: [This article](https://www.primetimer.com/news/stranger-things-season-1-jonathan-scene-edited) says it has been confirmed by people who have the DVDs. I've seen this story pop up on a few different news outlets now but they all seem to have come from [a tiktok video](https://www.tiktok.com/@joshy.bassetts/video/7122885920428330286?_t=8UBFZL04fCU&_r=1) and then [a follow-up twitter thread](https://twitter.com/Katie_Murphy776/status/1521594298361430016?s=20&t=MSXHy0KBiM32j3PoRJpduA)

Comment: With recent and original copies of all the videos, I could estimate their similarity using a variety of methods and identify all the places where things had been changed. However, that can be a time-consuming and difficult process without copies that match pixel-for-pixel and frame-for-frame except for the changes, so I will not be doing it now. Maybe next weekend.

Comment: In fact, I will definitely do it, since it is a good project to hone my skills for my job. But again, not today, because it will take time to get everything together, write the code and run the comparison. Audio will be easier, but will need to be done separately.

Comment: So, just got [this announcement](https://twitter.com/strangerwriters/status/1551901196700590080) via Twitter that denies the TikTok speculation and throws the whole premise of the question off.

Comment: @FredricShope that's a valid great answer!

Comment: I will still do it for practice, but I do not expect to find anything.